# Angular directive scope variable undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access my scope variables in `link` but they appear undefined

```
/** @ngInject */
function tablePagination() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: require('./tablePagination.html'),
    scope: {
      currentPage: '=',
      totalPages: '=',
      totalCount: '=',
      perPage: '='
    },
    link: function (scope) {
      console.log(scope.currentPage, scope) // scope.currentPage is undefined
    }
  }
}

// controller for authlogin
module.exports = tablePagination
```

I also tried using `@` rather than `=` and changed the binding to using `{{}}` but its still undefined. I could use `$observe` but I want to get values for multiple attributes at once to do some computation. Whats the best way to do this?

**HTML Code**

```
 <table-pagination
    current-page="$ctrl.tableMeta.currentPage"
    total-count="$ctrl.tableMeta.totalCount"
    total-pages="$ctrl.tableMeta.totalPages"
    per-page="$ctrl.tableMeta.perPage"></table-pagination>
```

**UPDATE**: I wonder if its because the directive is not getting updated values from `$ctrl.tableMeta` which is coming from API/Async

**SOLUTION!**: Oh I discovered my mistake was I need to use `$watch` otherwise it gets the old value which is by default undefined, since its not set async by API yet

```
scope.$watch('currentPage', () => {
  scope.start = (scope.currentPage - 1) * scope.perPage + 1
  scope.end = Math.min(scope.currentPage * scope.perPage, scope.totalCount)
})
```

Comment: provide your html when you used your directive.

Comment: `currentPage` Needs to be passed from the HTML!

Comment: can you share your tablePagination.html?

Comment: @Curiousdev, added HTML

Comment: @SureshB added HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just an example i hope it will clear few things up.

**gridPagination.html**

```
<label>current Page:</label><span>{{ currentPage }}</span>
<br>
<label>Total Pages:</label> {{ totalPages }}
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

**mainController.js**

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'My Grid';
}]);
```

**gridDirective.js**

```
app.directive('grid', gridPagination);

function gridPagination() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      currentPage: '=',
      totalPages: '=',
      totalCount: '=',
      perPage: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'gridPagination.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.currentPage);
      console.log(scope.totalPages);
      console.log(scope.totalCount);
      console.log(scope.perPage);
    }
  };
};
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  </head>   
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <grid current-page="3" total-pages= "30" total-count="10" per-page="2"></grid>
    </div>        
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="mainController.js"></script>
    <script src="gridDirective.js"></script>
  </body>    
</html>
```

[plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/ZMyVH6BxCBTGmIIoSIPY/)

Comment: I find that this works, but once I use a dynamic attribute `current-page=$ctrl.tableMeta.currentPage` for example, it breaks. I think the directive is not getting the value of currentPage when its set by API?

Comment: Ok I discovered I need to use `$watch`

Comment: Great @JiewMeng